# Is it possible to override On breakpoint Debug Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging

In Flutter, it is possible to run some code on hot reload with the following:

```
  @override
  void reassemble() {
    print("reassemble");
    // code here
    // player.release();
    // newGame();
    super.reassemble();
  }
```

I have another problem, my app plays some songs and when it hits a breakpoints, the song keeps playing. It is very distracting to listen to the song while debugging. And there is no way to stop it besides releasing the debugger.

Is it possible to override On breakpoint Debug Flutter?

Something like:

```
  @override
  void onBreakpoint() {
    print("hit breakpoint");
    player.pause();
    super.onBreakpoint();
  }
```

Comment: which package you've used for player?